# how to load interface as a autowired from parent module in cucumber

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired, cucumber-java

I am able to load all the parent module applicationContext bean definitions. But when I am using `@Autowired` on one of the interfaces I get the following exception:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'automationUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'testClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.test.clients.testClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Any one can help on that.

Comment: check if bean com.test.clients.testClient is registered with spring container (either by declaring in xml or @component annotation at class level)

Comment: You can not load interface directly.... you must provide an implementation of the interface